# R dataframe to 3-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, matrix

Due to the size of my data, using loops is not an option (my current method). A simplified example of what I want to achieve is converting a 4 column dataframe (3 columns of index and 1 column is the value) into a 3-dimensional array.

E.g.

```
| Index1 | Index2 | Index3 | Value |
|--------|--------|--------|-------|
| 1      | 1      | 1      | 3     |
| 1      | 1      | 2      | 9     |
| 1      | 1      | 3      | 8     |
| 1      | 2      | 1      | 4     |
| 1      | 2      | 2      | 4     |
| 1      | 2      | 3      | 9     |
| 2      | 1      | 1      | 1     |
| 2      | 1      | 2      | 7     |
| ...    | ...    | ...    | ...   |
```

So that the three-dimensional array called matrix would have the value
matrix[1,1,1]=3 etc. It is important that the ordering of indices is conserved.

I have included my code for reference (R: Shiny) but I answers to the simplified question given I can adapt as appropriate. Thanks for your help.

```
    ### Replacement - replace matrix zeros with counts
    dataMatrix<-reactive({
        inFile<-input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        else {

          #We create a progress bar to inform the user of length of time
          stages<-length$lon*length$lat*length$time
          currStage<-0
          withProgress(message = 'Creating Data Matrix', value = 0, {

            #FOR LOOP TO POPULATE NEW MATRIX REPLACING ZERO VALUES
            dataMatrix<-array(rep(0, length$lon*length$lat*length$time), c(length$lon,length$lat,length$time))
            for (splitLon in 1:length$lon){
              for (splitLat in 1:length$lat){
                for (splitTime in 1:length$time){
                  value <- aggDf() %>%
                    select(lonGroup, latGroup, timeGroup, n) %>%
                    filter(lonGroup==levels(categories$lon)[splitLon], latGroup==levels(categories$lat)[splitLat], timeGroup==levels(categories$time)[splitTime]) %>%
                    select(n)

                  #Convert n (i.e. count of category) to numeric
                  value <- as.numeric(value)

                  #If nothing found place 0 in matrix instead of NA
                  if (is.na(value)){
                    value<-0
                  }

                  #Replace matrix value
                  #Note that we want to fill lat up inverse i.e. since small lat at bottom of map not top
                  dataMatrix[((length$lat +1)-splitLat),splitLon,splitTime]<- value

                  #Add 1 to currentStage
                  currStage<-currStage +1

                  #Increase and show progress bar
                  incProgress(1/stages, detail = paste("Stage", currStage, "of", stages))

                }
              }
            }
          })
          return(dataMatrix)
        }
      })
```

Comment: @Jaap thank you for modifying my markdown

Comment: Some combination of `order` and `array` will suffice. Just play around with those functions until you get your desired outcome. Like `array(myDat$Val, c(3, 2, 3))` or `array(myDat$Val[order(myDat$index3, myDat$index1)], c(3, 2, 3))`.