# Convert R dataframe into a 3-dimensional array

Tags: r

I have an R dataframe that has N rows and 6 columns. For exemplification I will use following column names: "theDate","theIndex","Component_1","Component_2","Component_3","Component_4"

I am trying to convert it to a 3 dimensional array, with first dimension corresponding to "theDate", second dimension to "theIndex" and third dimension to the values of the components.

To give an example, the expression NewArray[2,4,3] will display the 2-nd element from "theDate" column, the 4-th element from "theIndex" column and the value of Component_3 that is on same row as the 2-nd value from "theDate" column and the 4-th value from "theIndex" column.

I have looked into using abind, narray, and a combination of  apply/split/abind, without full success.

The closest question I found on SO is this one: [Link SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221173/r-dataframe-to-3-dimensional-array), but I could not generalize it along same lines as the answer found there.

The desired multidimensional array has dimensions (5, 7, 4). First two dimensions are corresponding to 5 distinct elements in "theDate" column and to 7 distinct elements in "theIndex" column, while the third dimension corresponds to the 4 additional columns in dataframe: Component_1,...,Component_4)

Here is a small piece of code to create the dataframe, and to create an empty multidimensional array of desired dimensions

EDIT: I have also added a piece of code which appears to work, and I would be interested in other solutions

```
  `%>%` <- dplyr::`%>%`

  base::set.seed(seed = 1785)

  setOfComponents <-c("Component_1","Component_2","Component_3","Component_4")

  setOfDates <- c(234, 342, 456, 678, 874)
  setOfIndices <- c(2, 7, 11, 15, 24, 36, 56)

  numIndices <- length(setOfIndices)
  numDates <- length(setOfDates)
  numElementsComponent <- numIndices * numDates

  theDF <- base::data.frame(
    theDate = c(base::rep(x = setOfDates[1],times = numIndices),
                base::rep(x = setOfDates[2],times = numIndices),
                base::rep(x = setOfDates[3],times = numIndices),
                base::rep(x = setOfDates[4],times = numIndices),
                base::rep(x = setOfDates[5],times = numIndices)),
    theIndex = base::rep(x = setOfIndices,times = numDates),
    Component_1 = stats::runif(n = numElementsComponent, min = 0, max = 100),
    Component_2 = stats::runif(n = numElementsComponent, min = 0, max = 100),
    Component_3 = stats::runif(n = numElementsComponent, min = 0, max = 100),
    Component_4 = stats::runif(n = numElementsComponent, min = 0, max = 100) )

   theNewDF <- theDF %>%
       tidyr::gather(key = "IdxComp", value = "ValueComp", Component_1, Component_2, Component_3, Component_4)

   newArray <- array(theNewDF$ValueComp, dim = c(length(unique(theDF$theDate)),length(unique(theDF$theIndex)),length(setOfComponents)))
```

Comment: Any particular reason for prefixing some (but not all of) your function calls with `base::` and `stats::`?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want, could you give a numeric example ? What will be the size of the differents dimensions of your array ?

Comment: The 3D array will have dimensions dim = c(5,7,4). Essentially there are 5 distinct elements in "theDate" column, 7 distinct elements in "theIndex" column, and the third dimension corresponds to the 4 additional columns in dataframe: Component_1,...,Component_4   . The code above has constructed the dataframe this way

Comment: `I am trying to convert it to a 3 dimensional array, with first dimension corresponding to "theDate", second dimension to "theIndex" and third dimension to the values of the components.` Then we will have N*(6-2)*length(TheIndex)*length(TheDate) values, which is 4 dimensions. No?

Comment: I should have been more clear indeed. I was looking for Array[i,j,k], where k would correspond to the index of the component: 1 for Component_1, 2 for Component_2 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the tidyr package. 
I think you want the `gather` function.

See the package, or the descriptions here:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Comment: Indeed tidyr::gather was the way to go. I have already edited my question to incorporate gather and to obtain the solution. Thank you